# How do I render values of input elements into a div correctly?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to grab an input value with javascript and render it into a div element. What do I do to make it work?

I'm using querySeclector to grab the input value. When I hardcode it like this:

```
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Hello World";
```

It works but doesn't when I replace **"Hello World"** with the variable that stores the input value and when I do a console.log, I get nothing back even though there are no errors.

HTML

```
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="values">
            <input id="firstinput" type="text" placeholder="Enter 2 positive figures">
            <button id="submit">Submit</button>
        </div>
        <div id="result"></div>
    </div>

<script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
let submitButton = document.querySelector("#submit"),
showResult = document.getElementById("result").innerHTML,
weightsForLeftAndRightSides = document.querySelector("#firstinput").value;

submitButton.addEventListener("click", weightBalancer);

function weightBalancer() {
    showResult = weightsForLeftAndRightSides;
    console.log(weightsForLeftAndRightSides);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need get input value inside weightBalancer when sumbit button clicked

```
function weightBalancer() {
    var weightsForLeftAndRightSides = document.querySelector("#firstinput").value;
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = weightsForLeftAndRightSides;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if i understood your question, you can write this code to put the user input in div tag:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,
  initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA_Compatible" content="ie=edge">

  <title> Test</title>
  <script >
    /*to put the user input in div tag*/
    function myFunction(){
      const userInput=document.querySelector("#firstinput");
      const output=document.querySelector("#result");

      output.innerHTML=userInput.value;//this parte overwrite the first input
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <body>
  <div id="container">
      <div id="values">
          <input id="firstinput" type="text" placeholder="Enter 2 positive figures">
          <button id="submit" onclick="myFunction()">Submit</button>
      </div>
      <div id="result"></div>
  </div>


</body>
</html>
```

Hope this helps